# Can someone tell me a book of linear algebra where polynomials are treated widely and closely?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Does anyone know a linear algebra textbook where polynomials are treated in the concept of an algebra and series, i know there is an appendix at Friedberg 4-th ed L.Algebra but there is no algebra involved there just some theorems about their properties